# Do while loop giving unexpected output

Tags: c, do-while

```
int main(void)
 {    char ch;

  for(; ;) 
   {   
       do
        { printf("\n Press 'a' for case a ");
          printf("\n Press 'b' for case b ");
          printf("\n Press 'c' for case c ");

           scanf("%c",&ch);
        }while(ch!='a' && ch!='b' && ch!='c');

    }

   return 0;
     }
```

> I/p(1):'z' (say)     o/p(1):
>        Press 'a' for case a
>        Press 'b' for case b
>        Press 'c' for case c
>        Press 'a' for case a
>        Press 'b' for case b
>        Press 'c' for case c
>        i/p(2): "NULL(enter)"
>        o/p(2):Press 'a' for case a
>        Press 'b' for case b
>               Press 'c' for case c

Please explain the reason behind this kind of output

Comment: Is there some reason you're printing your newlines first rather than last?

Comment: Think. You press two keys in the first input. Fix the problem by adding a space (or any whitespace character) before `%c`.

Comment: I pressed only one key only.

Comment: You press `z` and then press enter. Yes, enter is also a valid input for `%c` in the `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `do`..`while` loop runs twice when you enter an invalid character 'z' because there are two characters to read -- the 'z' you entered, and a newline that follows it (from pressing `enter`).

If you don't want that behavior, you could read the whole line and keep the first character instead of reading a single character character, such as in this example with `getchar()`:

```
do {
  int gcres;
  printf("\n Press 'a' for case a ");
  printf("\n Press 'b' for case b ");
  printf("\n Press 'c' for case c ");
  ch = getchar();
  while ((gcres = getchar()) != '\n' && gcres != EOF);
} while(ch!='a' && ch!='b' && ch!='c');
```

where `ch = getchar();` reads the first char into `ch`, and

```
while ((gcres = getchar()) != '\n' && gcres != EOF);
```

reads the remaining characters in the line (up to and including the next newline).  The `&& gcres != EOF` part just checks for error/end-of-file to prevent an infinite loop on error or end of file.

Or, alternately, you could add a space before `%c` in your `scanf()` format string:

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
```

which will skip any whitespace before reading the character for `ch`.  That will still leave the following newline in the stream, though, so a later read may need to handle it.